# WMV file in an ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, wmv

How do I embed a WMV file in an ASP.NET Web page? I want it visible as a player, not just a link. Is there an ASP.NET control for this? I don't see one on the VS 2008 toolbar, and can't find one in the help. And I'm not yet ready to move this site to Silverlight, where media is really easy.

Answer (score 3):

Check if your project is targeted for 3.5. If it is, you should be able to see the mediaplayer control in your toolbox.

WMV can be shown in Firefox with this plugin:
http://port25.technet.com/pages/windows-media-player-firefox-plugin-download.aspx

WMV can be shown in QuickTime with this plugin:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=915D874D-D747-4180-A400-5F06B1B5E559&displaylang=en

Anthony :-)

Comment: I wasn't familiar with MediaPlayer control, it's seriously sweet and nice and easy to get into Silverlight media dev

Comment: I think I started this project as 2.0. I'll check. Thanks!

Comment: Nope. Property pages say 3.5. And I build a new 3.5 Web app, and Media Player's still not in the toolbox. This is my fallback machine. I wonder if there's a service pack I haven't installed.

Comment: Did you install Silverlight? If you did, you should be able to go to Tools -> Choose Toolbox Items, and be able to see the Silverlight tab?

Answer (score 0):

WMV is primarily a Microsoft file format.  There is no inherent browser support for this format, so you're going to need a browser plugin to play it.

I'm pretty sure you can embed Windows Media Player on a page to play it, but that'll limit you to clients running Windows and who happen to have Media Player installed.

If you need to support a wide audience, I'd seriously consider re-encoding your video to something like FLV and using a Flash based video player.  I haven't got statistics to hand that back this up - but Flash Video is the most widely supported video format in the browser.