# How to play a wmv file in my asp.net webpage?

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to play a wmv file in my asp.net webpage? Thanks!
Will an end use need install some control when he access the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to convert your videos to Flash Video (FLV) and use an embedded Flash video player (this is YouTube's approach), or use a Silverlight counterpart that may play WMV natively (you don't need to convert to Flash Video, but Silverlight isn't available in all browsers and/or platforms).

Check this page: http://flowplayer.org/

Answer (score 0):

already discussed on SO: [WMV file in an ASP.NET page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329532/wmv-file-in-an-asp-net-page)

Answer (score 0):

This guy seems to have all the answers for embedding WMV
http://www.jakeludington.com/project_studio/20050914_embedding_windows_media_player_wmv.html

Answer (score 0):

Videos can be played "inline" or by a "helper", depending on the HTML element you use.

> ***Inline Videos***

When a video is included in a web page it is called inline video.

If you plan to use inline videos in your web applications, be aware that many people find inline videos annoying. Also note that some users might have turned off the inline video option in their browser.

Our best advice is to include inline videos only in web pages where the user expects to see a video. An example of this is a page which opens after the user has clicked on a link to see the video.

> ***Using A Helper (Plug-In)***

A helper application is a program that can be launched by the browser to "help" playing a video. Helper applications are also called Plug-Ins.

Helper applications can be launched using the  or the  tag.

One great advantage of using a helper application is that you can let some (or all) of the player settings be controlled by the user.

Most helper applications allow manual (or programmed) control over the volume settings and play functions like rewind, pause, stop and play.

> ***Using The 'embed' Tag***

The purpose of the  tag is to embed multimedia elements in web page.

The following code fragment displays an AVI file embedded in a web page:

Example:

```
<embed src="video.avi" />
```

Note: The embed tag is deprecated. The World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) recommend using the object tag instead.

> ***Using The 'object' Tag***

The purpose of the  tag is to embed multimedia elements in web page.

The following code fragment displays an AVI file embedded in a web page:

Example

```
<object data="video.avi" type="video/avi" />
```

> ***Using A Hyperlink***

If a web page includes a hyperlink to a media file, most browsers will use a "helper application" to play the file.

The following code fragment displays a link to an AVI file. If a user clicks on the link, the browser will launch a helper application, like Windows Media Player to play the AVI file:

Example:-

```
 <a href="video.avi">Play a video file</a>
```

Comment: Does it mean that different browsers will launch different helper application and install different Plug-Ins when I insert the following code to my webpage?

Comment: @ Paul:- Which helper application or plug in would launch entirely depends on what you have used as HTML element, in your source code. So it means it won't change in diff browsers.